# Placeholder cell in a UITableView

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

Suppose I have a `UITableView` with two sections. If the data source for that section is empty I would like to display a placeholder cell with the text "*Section Name* is empty."

How can I do that?

Code

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 1)
    {
        return @"Section One";
    }
    if(section == 0)
    {
        return @"Section Two";
    }
    return @"";
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if (section == 1) 
    {
        return self.sectionOne.count;
    }
    else
    {
        return self.sectionTwo.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    NSArray *theSource =[[NSArray alloc] init];

    if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        theSource = self.sectionOne;
    }
    else
    {
        theSource = self.sectionTwo;
    }

    // See if there's an existing cell we can reuse
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
if (cell == nil) 
    {
        // No cell to reuse => create a new one
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
        cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        // Continue creating cell
        }
  }
```

Comment: please post code of what you have already!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the following functions in your UITableViewDataSource (pseudo code):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (datasource == empty)
        return 1;
    else
        return [datasource count];
}
```

And:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (datasource == empty)
         return stub cell;
    else
         return regular cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather that doing any thing in table view; i would have checked in data model and may update the data model accordingly.

You are displaying the section title from your section title array (i assume);

You can check, if the row/record is there for that section exist or not; if not then update your section title array accordingly;

```
sectionTitleArray = [@"First Section", @"Second Section", @"Third Section"]
```

> rowValueArray = [[NSArray
>   arrayWithObjects:@"First1",@"First2"],[NSArray array],[NSArray
>   arrayWithObjects:@"Third1",@"Third3"]
>
> if([[rowValueArray objectAtIndex:1]count]<0){
>
> //row is empty for
>   second section; **
>
> **then update sectionTitleArray**
>
> sectionTitleArray =
>   [@"First Section", @"Section is empty", @"Third Section"]
>
> }

**Its just a scenario, not actual code.**